# How to feed time series as a feature itself in neural network training in R?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, classification, recurrent-neural-network

I am using both [NeuralNet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/index.html) and [NNEt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html)  for time series classification.

Here is a reproducible example. Lets suppose the first five columns are values of time series and last is the label.   I know I can use features like Max, Minimum, standard deviation, Number of peaks etc but is there a way I can use the time series itself as a feature as well?

Please note I have lots of data and lots of data points in the time series so I am aware of the efficiency of the model. Just is there any way to include a vector(time series) as a feature itself?

```
0.02206     0.0589      0.06946     0.06335     0.06244    1
0.002254    0.00246     0.003002    0.002636    0.002651   1
0.0004702   0.0005436   0.0005598   0.0005302   0.0005798  1    
0.0005608   0.000515    0.0005903   0.0005713   0.0006304  2
0.0006943   0.0006895   0.0007982   0.0006256   0.0006371  2    
0.03522     0.03625     0.03735     0.03424     0.03436    2
0.01285     0.01128     0.01115     0.01024     0.01088    1
```